# android image auto detect colors

Tags: android, image, image-processing, imagelibrary

I am trying to do something like this since last 2 weeks.

When user captures a photo using camera, it should auto detect colors/object and highlight it crop that photo. User should be able to change/resize/decide the crop area, and it should be cropped when click on "Crop" button. See below example screenshot.

[image]

As shown in screenshot, I captured a photo of a paper on the chair. It automatically detected the paper area and covered it with orange border. I can change/resize that orange area for cropping also. I take this screenshot from **[Drive Axle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eleostech.driveaxle)** app.

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stanley Yes, I am trying to implement OpenCV. But still no luck with it.

Comment: no luck implementing openCV at all or just no luck with your paper detection?